# Add FocusListener to a 2D JTextField array

Tags: java, arrays, listener

So I want to `setText` a string called `value` when I click on **one** of the `JTextfield`. I read about adding FocusListener to a JTextField but couldn't find anything about adding it to a 2D JTextField array. I'm having trouble making it work.

```
private int totalX = 20;
private int totalY = 20;

private JTextField[][] fields;
fields = new JTextField[totalX][totalY];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the listener on each `JTextField` object if you want each field may react to the click.

```
private JTextField[][] fields = new JTextField[totalX][totalY];
... // create JTextField objects of the array

// then iterate on the array to add the Listener
for (JTextField field : fields){
    field.addFocusListener(new MyFocusListener());
}
```

You should use one `FocusListener` instance by `JTextField` object if the `FocusListener` implementation is stateful.
Otherwise you could reuse the same `FocusListener` instance for all `JTextField` objects.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. `FocusListener` is better when I used `MouseListener` I had to click multiple times before the click registers. Anyway, thank you for your help.